# How to make animated loader in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple animated loader using html and css.
I am not able to make the animation of uniform thickness.
[i am able to achieve this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oHtk.png)

```css
.circle{
    border:5px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    animation-name:circle;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes circle {
    0% {border-right-style:hidden;}
    33% {border-bottom-style:hidden;}
    66% {border-left-style:hidden}
    100% {border-top:hidden;}
    
}
```

```html
<div class="anime">
          <div class = "circle">
            
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to animate by just going 360 degree?

Answer (score 1):

```css
html {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.circle, .circle::after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  animation-name: circle;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  content: "";
}
.circle::after {
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.27rem; left: -2rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation-name: none;
}
@keyframes circle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate( 0 );
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate( 360deg );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anime">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```